# how to fix sharepoint stop working after changing server name?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

how to fix sharepoint 2010 stop working after changing the server name.
After changed sharepoint server name and SQL instance name changed my SP not running. 
Showing the error."**Cannot connect to the configuration database**"

how to resolve these issues?
Please guide me or share any reference link.
 **Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check if you have run the powershell command below:

   Rename-SPServer -Identity OriginalServerName -Name NewServerName

Or

```
stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername <oldServerName> -newservername <newServerName>  
#putting in the actual name of your old SQL server and new SQL server
```

2. Reset IIS.

More reference:

[Rename-SPServer.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/rename-spserver?view=sharepoint-ps)

And if you want to rename the SQL server name, you could refer to the article below.

[Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/rename-a-computer-that-hosts-a-stand-alone-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

There is a similar post:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d1b1bd7-21f8-4bc5-b056-0436f8ffed89/cannot-connect-to-a-configuration-database-after-renaming-windows-7-computer?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these steps

1) Go to Services windows using services.msc

2) Select your service to start

3) Right-click->Properties->LogOn and then check "local system account"

4) Start or Restart your service

and hope it will works

If it didn't work please refer these links once

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/47e26477-cce4-4eaf-a65e-81e906604432/quotcannot-connect-to-the-configuration-databasequot-when-going-for-sharepoint-2010-central?forum=sharepointadminprevious

https://mysharepointsolution.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/how-to-fix-cannot-connect-to-the-configuration-database/